# Problems With Contours Using Python's matplotlib 3D API

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, contour, projection

I'm trying to do something similar to [this](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/mplot3d/contour3d_3.html) 3D example from the docs, but with a point cloud instead of a smooth surface.  The example projects 2D contours onto each of the three coordinate planes.  This shows that I'm able to do that onto the xy-plane.

[image: 2D contour successfully added to xy-plane.]

When I try doing the same onto the other two planes, I get either a weird contour collapsed down to a thin strip,

[image: 2D contour on yz-plane collapsed into a thin strip.]

or an exception way beyond my reach in the bowels of *matplotlib*.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py", line 519, in _draw_idle
    self.draw()
  File ".../matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 433, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File ".../matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File ".../matplotlib/figure.py", line 1475, in draw
    renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
  File ".../matplotlib/image.py", line 141, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File ".../mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 281, in draw
    reverse=True)):
  File ".../mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 280, in <lambda>
    key=lambda col: col.do_3d_projection(renderer),
  File ".../mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/art3d.py", line 226, in do_3d_projection
    self._segments3d]
  File ".../mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/art3d.py", line 225, in <listcomp>
    proj3d.proj_trans_points(points, renderer.M) for points in
  File ".../mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/proj3d.py", line 188, in proj_trans_points
    xs, ys, zs = zip(*points)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)
```

Here's an example of the problem.  This version works.  Uncomment one or both of the calls to `ax.contour()` in the `plot()` function to see the weird contours, or more likely, the exception.

```python
import math
import sys
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d
import numpy as np
import scipy.spatial

#np.random.seed(4)
numPts = 1000                                       # number of points in cloud
scatter = False                         # adds scatter plot to show point cloud


def main():
    (pts, f) = mkData()                                # create the point cloud
    tris = mkTris(pts)                                         # triangulate it
    plot(pts, tris, f)                                                # plot it


def plot(pts, tris, f):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")

    cmap = plt.get_cmap("coolwarm")

    collec = ax.plot_trisurf(tris, pts[:, 2], cmap=cmap)
    colors = np.mean(f[tris.triangles], axis=1)
    collec.set_array(colors)
    collec.autoscale()

    (xr, yr, zr, xMin, yMin, zMin, zMax) = resample(ax, tris, f)
    ax.set_zlim(zMin, zMax)      # default always includes zero for some reason

    #
    # Uncomment one or both of these lines to see the problem.
    #
    ax.contour(xr, yr, zr, 10, zdir="z", cmap=cmap, offset=zMin)
    #ax.contour(xr, yr, zr, 10, zdir="x", cmap=cmap, offset=xMin)
    #ax.contour(xr, yr, zr, 10, zdir="y", cmap=cmap, offset=yMin)

    if scatter:
        ax.scatter(pts[:, 0], pts[:, 1], pts[:, 2], alpha=0.1)

    ax.set_xlabel("x")
    ax.set_ylabel("y")
    ax.set_zlabel("z")
    fig.colorbar(collec, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
    plt.show()


def mkData():
    """
    Create a random point cloud near a random plane, and define a function on
    the plane for colors and contours.
    """
    offset = 1                   # generate points near a unit square, xy-plane
    pts = 2 * np.random.rand(numPts, 3) - 1
    pts[:, 2] = offset * (2 * np.random.rand(numPts) - 1)

    x = 2 * np.ravel(pts[:, 0])
    y = 2 * np.ravel(pts[:, 1])
    f = x * np.exp(-x**2 - y**2)      # just some function for colors, contours

    width = 100                       # scale unit square to a larger rectangle
    height = 20
    pts[:, 0] *= width
    pts[:, 1] *= height

    (e1, e2, e3) =[2 * np.pi * np.random.rand() for _ in range(3)]
    (c1, s1) = (math.cos(e1), math.sin(e1))           # rotate scaled rectangle
    (c2, s2) = (math.cos(e2), math.sin(e2))
    (c3, s3) = (math.cos(e3), math.sin(e3))
    Ta2b = np.array((                     # do not have scipy.spatial.transform
        [               c1  *c2,       s2,              -s1 * c2],
        [s1 * s3 - c1 * s2 * c3,  c2 * c3, c1 *s3 + s1 * s2 * c3],
        [s1 * c3 + c1 * s2 * s3, -c2 * s3, c1 *c3 - s1 * s2 * s3]))

    pts = (Ta2b @ pts.T).T

    dist = 500                                 # translate away from the origin
    Ra2bNb = dist * (2 * np.random.rand(3, 1) - 1)

    pts += Ra2bNb.T

    return (pts, f)


def mkTris(pts):                                  # triangulate the point cloud
    u = np.ravel(pts[:, 0])
    v = np.ravel(pts[:, 1])

    try:
        return mpl.tri.Triangulation(u, v)
    except (ValueError, RuntimeError) as ex:
        sys.exit(f"Unable to compute triangulation: {ex}.")


def resample(ax, tris, f):         # resample triangulation onto a regular grid
    (xMin, xMax) = ax.get_xlim()
    (yMin, yMax) = ax.get_ylim()
    (zMin, zMax) = ax.get_zlim()

    x = np.linspace(xMin, xMax, 30)
    y = np.linspace(yMin, yMax, 30)

    (xm, ym)=np.meshgrid(x, y)

    interp = mpl.tri.triinterpolate.LinearTriInterpolator(tris, f)
    zm = interp(xm, ym)

    return (xm, ym, zm, xMin, yMin, zMin, zMax)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is with *matplotlib* 2.2.2 and 3.1.1.  Thanks for any help you can provide to get contours on all three planes, like the demo.

Jim

Comment: The arrays I'm passing to `ax.contour()` are `numpy.ndarray` for *x* and *y*, but `numpy.ma.core.MaskedArray` for *z*.  I don't know why it should matter, but it's probably related to the weird "strips" and the exception when projecting contours onto the *xz*- and *yz*-planes, but not the *xy*-plane.  So progress, but still searching.

Comment: I submitted this as an [issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/18695).

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567001/3d-plot-with-matplotlib) appears to be a similar problem, but with filled contours, not a random point cloud, and the complaint is different.  There, the focus is on a weird blank spot, and the known limitation in *matplotlib*'s depth sorting.

Comment: Thanks to a developer on the *matplotlib* development team for pointing out the error that's causing this.  The problem calls to `ax.contour()` are passing interpolated function values as the *z*-coordinate.  The fix is to interpolate *z*-coordinates too in the resampling, and pass them to those calls instead.  I'll post a fixed version in a day or two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *matplotlib* developer pointed out that the resampling was wrong.  After fixing that, here's the corrected plot.

[image]

For coordinate planes that see the data edge-on, like the *yz*-plane in this case, the contours can look a little wonky.  That's expected, since the data can approach being multi-valued.  The *xz*-plane contours look pretty ragged too.  I suspect both problems would improve by triangulating and contouring each plane individually, instead of favoring the *xy*-plane as done here.

Here's the fixed test script.  The only important changes were in `plot()` and `resample()`.

```
import math
import sys
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d
import numpy as np
import scipy.spatial

#np.random.seed(4)
numPts = 1000                                       # number of points in cloud
numGrid = 120      # number of points in meshgrid used in resample for contours
scatter = False                         # adds scatter plot to show point cloud


def main():
    (pts, f) = mkData()                                # create the point cloud
    tris = mkTris(pts)                                         # triangulate it
    plot(pts, tris, f)                                                # plot it


def plot(pts, tris, f):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")

    cmap = plt.get_cmap("coolwarm")

    collec = ax.plot_trisurf(tris, pts[:, 2], cmap=cmap)
    colors = np.mean(f[tris.triangles], axis=1)
    collec.set_array(colors)
    collec.autoscale()

    (xr, yr, zr, fr, xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax, zMin, zMax) = resample(ax, tris,
       pts, f)

    ax.set_xlim(xMin, xMax)      # default always includes zero for some reason
    ax.set_ylim(yMin, yMax)
    ax.set_zlim(zMin, zMax)

    ax.contour(xr, yr, fr, 10, zdir="z", cmap=cmap, offset=zMin)
    ax.contour(fr, yr, zr, 10, zdir="x", cmap=cmap, offset=xMin)
    ax.contour(xr, fr, zr, 10, zdir="y", cmap=cmap, offset=yMax)

    if scatter:
       ax.scatter(pts[:, 0], pts[:, 1], pts[:, 2], alpha=0.1)

    ax.set_xlabel("x")
    ax.set_ylabel("y")
    ax.set_zlabel("z")
    fig.colorbar(collec, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
    plt.show()


def mkData():
    """
    Create a random point cloud near a random plane, and define a function on
    the plane for colors and contours.
    """
    offset = 1                   # generate points near a unit square, xy-plane
    pts = 2 * np.random.rand(numPts, 3) - 1
    pts[:, 2] = offset * (2 * np.random.rand(numPts) - 1)

    x = 2 * np.ravel(pts[:, 0])
    y = 2 * np.ravel(pts[:, 1])
    f = x * np.exp(-x**2 - y**2)      # just some function for colors, contours

    width = 100                       # scale unit square to a larger rectangle
    height = 20
    pts[:, 0] *= width
    pts[:, 1] *= height

    (e1, e2, e3) =[2 * np.pi * np.random.rand() for _ in range(3)]
    (c1, s1) = (math.cos(e1), math.sin(e1))           # rotate scaled rectangle
    (c2, s2) = (math.cos(e2), math.sin(e2))
    (c3, s3) = (math.cos(e3), math.sin(e3))
    Ta2b = np.array((                     # do not have scipy.spatial.transform
        [               c1  *c2,       s2,              -s1 * c2],
        [s1 * s3 - c1 * s2 * c3,  c2 * c3, c1 *s3 + s1 * s2 * c3],
        [s1 * c3 + c1 * s2 * s3, -c2 * s3, c1 *c3 - s1 * s2 * s3]))

    pts = (Ta2b @ pts.T).T

    dist = 500                                 # translate away from the origin
    Ra2bNb = dist * (2 * np.random.rand(3, 1) - 1)

    pts += Ra2bNb.T

    return (pts, f)


def mkTris(pts):
    "Triangulate the point cloud."
    u = np.ravel(pts[:, 0])
    v = np.ravel(pts[:, 1])

    try:
        return mpl.tri.Triangulation(u, v)
    except (ValueError, RuntimeError) as ex:
        sys.exit(f"Unable to compute triangulation: {ex}.")


def resample(ax, tris, pts, f):
    "Resample the triangulation onto a regular grid for contours."
    (xMin, xMax) = ax.get_xlim()
    (yMin, yMax) = ax.get_ylim()
    (zMin, zMax) = ax.get_zlim()

    x = np.linspace(xMin, xMax, numGrid)
    y = np.linspace(yMin, yMax, numGrid)

    (xm, ym)=np.meshgrid(x, y)

    fInterp = mpl.tri.CubicTriInterpolator(tris, f)
    fm = fInterp(xm, ym)

    zInterp = mpl.tri.CubicTriInterpolator(tris, pts[:,2])
    zm = zInterp(xm, ym)

    return (xm, ym, zm, fm, xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax, zMin, zMax)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```